# How to make this Slideshow not automatic but click to change image

Tags: javascript, html

This code is a automatic slideshow and i want to make it so when you click next it goes to the next image and back to go to the previous image

My current code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "http://www.adactushousing.co.uk/images/upload/coverImage/Local%20Offer%20CCH.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "http://www.northantspfg.co.uk/resources/uploads/news/wordal13-021142.JPG"
var image3 = new Image()
image3.src = "http://hmstack.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/swimming-for-the-disabled.jpg"
var image4 = new Image()
image4.src = "http://www.northantspfg.co.uk/resources/uploads/news/HiResLocalOffer13-041205.jpg"
</script>
</head>


    <img src=\"images/pentagg.jpg\" width=\"500\" height=\"300\" name=\"slide\" /></p>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    var step=1;
    function slideit()
    {
        document.images.slide.src = eval(\"image\"+step+\".src\");
        if(step<4)
            step++;
        else
            step=1;
        setTimeout(\"slideit()\",2500);
    }
    slideit();
    </script>
```

Comment: Don't ever use `.eval()`. If you need it, it means your code has a problem.

Comment: what would i change it to?

Comment: You know how to increment/decrease the steps, so what's the difficult in doing it on a `click` event handler instead of using a `timeout`?

Comment: Also, why are you escaping all the quotes in your markup?

Comment: You could put all the images into an `array` and return the content by index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the function slideit() on page load, this is the reason that this work automaticly, do that, it's should work:

```
<button onclick="slideit()">Next image</button>

<script type=\"text/javascript\">
var step=1;
function slideit()
{
    document.images.slide.src = eval(\"image\"+step+\".src\");
    if(step<4)
        step++;
    else
        step=1;
}
</script>
```